# ASP Net UPDATE Command not working

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have the following UPDATE command (written in VB) in my code.

```
Dim currentUser As String = User.Identity.Name

    Dim myConnectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBConnection").ConnectionString
    Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand("UPDATE tblProfile SET Title= @Title, FirstName= @FirstName, LastName= @LastName, MiddleName= @MiddleName, HomePhoneNumber= @HomePhoneNumber, MobilePhoneNumber= @MobilePhoneNumber, Address= @Address, StreetName= @StreetName, StreetType= @StreetType, Suburb= @Suburb, PostCode= @PostCode, State= @State WHERE UserName = '" & currentUser & "'", New SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
    myCommand.Connection.Open()
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", Title.SelectedItem.Text)
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", FirstName.Text)
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", LastName.Text)
    If MiddleNames.Text = String.Empty Then
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleName", DBNull.Value)
    Else
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleName", MiddleNames.Text)
    End If
    If HomePhoneNumber.Text = String.Empty Then
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HomePhoneNumber", DBNull.Value)
    Else
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HomePhoneNumber", HomePhoneNumber.Text)
    End If
    If MobilePhoneNumber.Text = String.Empty Then
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobilePhoneNumber", DBNull.Value)
    Else
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobilePhoneNumber", MobilePhoneNumber.Text)
    End If
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", AddressNumber.Text)
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StreetName", StreetName.Text)
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StreetType", StreetType.SelectedItem.Text)
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Suburb", Suburb.Text)
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostCode", Postcode.Text)
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", State.SelectedItem.Text)

    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    myCommand.Connection.Close()

    Dim myCommandPref As New SqlCommand("UPDATE tblPreferences SET Classical = @Classical, Comedy = @Comedy, Concerts = @Concerts, Dance = @Dance, DiningOut = @DiningOut, Exhibitions = @Exhibitions, Family = @Family, Festivals = @Festivals, Lifestyle = @Lifestyle, Musicals = @Musicals, Opera = @Opera, Rock = @Rock, Sports = @Sports, Theatre = @Theatre WHERE UserName = '" & currentUser & "'", New SqlConnection(myConnectionString))

    myCommandPref.Connection.Open()

    Dim boolClassical As Boolean = Preferences.Items(0).Selected
    myCommandPref.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Classical", boolClassical.ToString)

    Dim boolComedy As Boolean = Preferences1.Items(0).Selected
    myCommandPref.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comedy", boolComedy.ToString)

    Dim boolConcerts As Boolean = Preferences.Items(1).Selected
    myCommandPref.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Concerts", boolConcerts.ToString)

    Dim boolDance As Boolean = Preferences1.Items(1).Selected
    myCommandPref.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dance", boolDance.ToString)

    Dim boolDiningOut As Boolean = Preferences.Items(2).Selected
    myCommandPref.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DiningOut", boolDiningOut.ToString)

    Dim boolExhibitions As Boolean = Preferences1.Items(2).Selected
    myCommandPref.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Exhibitions", boolExhibitions.ToString)

    Dim boolFamily As Boolean = Preferences.Items(3).Selected
    myCommandPref.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Family", boolFamily.ToString)

    Dim boolFestivals As Boolean = Preferences1.Items(3).Selected
    myCommandPref.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Festivals", boolFestivals.ToString)

    Dim boolLifestyle As Boolean = Preferences.Items(4).Selected
    myCommandPref.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lifestyle", boolLifestyle.ToString)

    Dim boolMusicals As Boolean = Preferences1.Items(4).Selected
    myCommandPref.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Musicals", boolMusicals.ToString)

    Dim boolOpera As Boolean = Preferences.Items(5).Selected
    myCommandPref.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Opera", boolOpera.ToString)

    Dim boolRock As Boolean = Preferences1.Items(5).Selected
    myCommandPref.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rock", boolRock.ToString)

    Dim boolSports As Boolean = Preferences.Items(6).Selected
    myCommandPref.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sports", boolSports.ToString)

    Dim boolTheatre As Boolean = Preferences1.Items(6).Selected
    myCommandPref.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Theatre", boolTheatre.ToString)

    myCommandPref.ExecuteNonQuery()
    myCommandPref.Connection.Close()
```

When the user presses the button which fires that code, my page simply refreshes, but does not update the information in the database. I have looked around, and some people were saying you needed to have the primary key as the 'where' statement, so I made 'UserName' the primary key in both tables.

Could someone please help me to fix this.

Comment: 1. What is the value of currentUser going into this code? 2. Do you have access to SqlProfiler so you could watch what call is actually made against the database? 3. Have you debugged the code to see what values are passed into all the command parameters? 4. Are any errors occurring?

Comment: currentUser is the logged in user's user name. And there are no errors. The simply reloads as if the code for the button has been fired correctly, only nothing in the record is updated.

Comment: can you check sql profiler to see what sql query is fired.

Comment: My point for currentUser was have you checked that it's populated going into the code? Then you'd know which row it was attempting to update for certain. Still better to check the whole SQL statement from Profiler and try to run it manually

Comment: Yes, I know it is populated because on page load, it loads all their information into textboxes, so once they edit this information... this is where the problem is. They can't save. But I know the current user's profile is populated. I'm testing my own account.

Comment: I've been playing around with it, but still no luck. I've tried putting direct Values into the string for username and title and stuff like that, but nothing seems to work. I've figured out that, yes, username is the correct username and is in the database, but I just can't get it to work. Any other ideas? And I tried looking into SQL profiler, but don't know how to use (still learning).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went back to my code after a few months today, and after a brief search through, found the problem... I needed to include 'if not IsPostBack then...' to my Page_Load. I was resetting my page each time the button was pressed, which reset the fields on my page, thus sending the same information back to my server - I was updating my server with the same information.

For anyone with the same problem, this helped me:
http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1083